# vasync module assertion error

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am using the [vasync](https://github.com/davepacheco/node-vasync) module and keep getting the following error:

```
assert.js:89
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
  ^

AssertionError: 'fail' == 'pending'
```

In various places and not consistently. I feel like I am catching all possible errors.

Any thoughts on where to look or how to debug this.